# Jmeter Extractor to recover string into a file

Tags: string, file, jmeter, solution, extractor

I would like to know if someone knows the solution to recover a string into a file with Jmeter (the string could change each time into the file then is not static).
I have a file like this:

device-data-pdaa:
image: **acrsit.pippo.io/common/pippo-data-pippo-go-arm64:11.0.0**
container_name: go-data-sim
hostname: new-data-sim
networks:

I need to take the value after image: until the end of the line  (dynamic string in bold)
**Important: Into the file there are more occurrence of the word image**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read a file from local file system there are 2 options:

1. Use [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) like:

   [image]
2. Use [HTTP Request Sampler with `file` as the protocol](http://image:) and then a suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) for fetching the line you're looking for:

   [image]